# Why don't currently spoken languages have words for everything they encounter?

Tags: cross-linguistic, words

I have been getting translations of what I would consider are fairly basic words, into various languages, and have found some don't have translations and they either make up a translation on the spot (like you might do for a conlang or Sanskrit, for example), or they just use the English word.

Examples:

- penguin in tagalog is just "penguin" (no word exists, seems they just use the English word).
- pufferfish in tagalog doesn't exist
- shrimp in Amharic doesn't exist, was translated to የባህር እንስሳ አይነት
- crab, turkey, goose, lobster, squid, etc. also don't exist in Amharic. As does the word "moss".

I don't understand why all modern *spoken* languages wouldn't have words for everything every other language has words for... What is the reason for this?

I get languages not having cutting edge jargon like words for "transistor" or "random access memory" or "xenophobia" even, but for these pretty basic nouns, no words? Are there techniques or formal avenues for them to become adopted, or anything that can be done for these "missing" words?

I would have expected that as these languages met other languages (like English), they would do like Chinese does and invent a word for it which fit their paradigms best. Why isn't this being done? To me it says the language just isn't evolving, is that true? Or does the language still evolve but it just ignores these concepts?

I don't mean to be "English-centric", I would just have expected that once a new concept or object arrives in a language's view, they would create words for it, and it seems strange to still not have words for concepts the "world" is now familiar with, like "squid", "moss", "penguin", etc.. I get that they might not have experienced these things in their local environment, but now they most certainly have either through videos, images, texts, or traveling, or otherwise being exposed to it by colonizers or other people who come into their language geography.

Comment: Where do you think the word "penguin" came from?

Comment: I’m guessing the downvotes are primarily due to the fact that you’re asking about various other languages from an English-centric point of view, when in fact English is probably the most famous example of a language doing exactly what you’re describing: borrowing words piecemeal instead of making up new words from indigenous roots and words. Consider that at least two of the words you use as examples (_penguin_ and _turkey_) are **not** of English origin (though the precise origin of _penguin_ is uncertain).

Comment: ChatGPT was less harsh in receiving my question, maybe I'll start asking it from now on... "The phenomenon you're describing — where some languages lack words for certain concepts that are common in others — is a fascinating aspect of linguistic diversity and evolution." Obviously I am English-biased, but I wasn't aware I wasn't allowed to ask such questions.

Comment: This is one of the many questions about language that can really only be answered as "that's just the way the cookie crumbled" unless you want to look at every single common idea for which a natural language doesn't have a dedicated lexeme. They don't have those words because they don't have those words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lack of a native word for "shrimp" in Amharic can be predicted on geographical grounds, that shrimp don't live 400 miles inland, 8,000 ft up in the mountains. The English borrowing ሽሪምፕ is probably explained because shrimp may be imported into Ethiopia these days. The lack of a native English word for "reindeer" is likewise explained by the lack of reindeer in English-speaking territory, though nowadays reindeer have been imported into English-speaking territory, and vice-versa. There is no word at all in English for North Saami *gabba*, which is one of the myriad reindeer names (and we don't deal in reindeer), nor is there a word for a "yoik" (we don't do it). Typically, languages don't have words for things that don't exist in the culture, or which are of negligible cultural significance. I imagine that the Yup'ik word for zucchini is something like "zucchini" – you can always borrow a word. As for the [Tagalog word](https://tl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isdang_globo) "globe fish", it might be a recent invention – you would have to investigate whether they were ever exploited in the Philippines. Regardless of the historical details, you really can't say that there is no such word, all you can say is that it is not a historically-native word.

There may be social pressure to create new words from old roots, rather than borrowing words from a foreign language. But once a new concept or object arrives in a language's view, I expect that they will take the foreign language name for the new object, rather than fish around for some new term using indigenous morphemes. It does depend on how the item is introduced, for example Andean *camlla / cancha* is a twice-introduced, twice-named item, "Corn nuts" and "Giant Peruvian Inca Corn".

Answer (score 2):

Given that the turkey is native to North America, it's pretty unlikely that people in Ethiopia were discussing them before very recent times. Conversely, English-speakers weren't having many conversations about turacos…so when we did start talking about them, we borrowed the name from an African language (it's not clear which). Why didn't English-speakers come up with their own name for the bird? Why is there this flagrant gap in their basic vocabulary, missing a word for something every American child should know about?

Or, to use some more familiar concepts, why isn't there an English word for sushi, or tandoori, or baguette, or tortillas? Do English-speakers simply never think about these things? Is there anything that can be done to save English-speakers from this deficiency?

The point I'm trying to make is, English is *full* of words borrowed from other languages. It doesn't mean the language isn't evolving—exactly the opposite. It's one of the main ways languages get new words!

Often, when speakers of a language are introduced to a new concept, they'll borrow a word for it from the people who introduced them. (Other times they'll create a word from existing pieces, like "pufferfish".) That's just the way languages' vocabularies evolve. English isn't exempt from this by any means; it borrows words more freely than most others. English-speakers just don't tend to realize which words are borrowed and which are native, since to them, they're all just…words.

Comment: I am aware that English borrows many words, but I wasn't aware it borrowed "penguin" lol, it makes sense though. I guess I just find it unusual when a word with non-native morphology is plugged into a language (like the Tagalog case). It's like if they said "draconian" in Chinese, when Chinese doesn't have a lot of those morphemes... Guess it was just naive thinking.

Comment: @Lance Which word do you mean, for the morphology borrowing in Tagalog?

Comment: @Lance Though also, "draconian"'s morphology is actually Latin! _-ianus_ is a Latin suffix, whence French _-ien_ and then English _-ian_. This is what I mean about them all being just words—English has a _lot_ of loans from different places and we usually just don't think about them. (And that's not getting into calques…)